# Calculation of interaction of gravitational waves with a black hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, string-theory, gravitational-waves, ads-cft

We have a well understood interacting electromagnetic system, an electromagnetic wave interacting with an atom. We use perturbation theory to calculate what happens in such a system. The result is of course the phenomenon of stimulated emission, which has an important application in LASERs.

My question: Is there any way to do the gravitaional counter-part of the problem, that is interaction of a black hole with a gravitational wave(well, I agree that the correspondense is approximate of course), may be using AdS/CFT ?

Comment: Are you asking about "scattering" of a gravitational wave off a BH?

Comment: that is why i described the "corresponding" scenario in electromagnetism. When we say an e.m. wave scatter off an atom, (do?) we get the stimulated emission from the atom

Comment: try to look at: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382665/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235517/226902  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190632/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368435/226902 ...no need for ads/cft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you need AdS/CTF correspondence for that? There is a good derivation found [here](https://www.zarm.uni-bremen.de/fileadmin/user_upload/space_science/gravitational_theory/gravwave.pdf) (page 64 to 90). To give a quick overview:

You can calculate the propagation of gravitational waves on a background metric using pertubation theory in first order. You start with a pertubation of the metric tensor given by:
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{g}_{\mu\nu}
=g_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu}
\qquad\text{with}\qquad
|\delta g_{\mu\nu}|<1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{g}^{\mu\nu}
=g^{\mu\nu}-\delta g^{\mu\nu}
\qquad\text{with}\qquad
|\delta g_{\mu\nu}|>1.
\end{equation}
The different signs were explained by me [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703909/inverse-of-a-metric-under-variation) already. You can now calculate the Christoffel symbols, the Riemann curvature tensor and the Einstein tensor only in first order of the pertubation.

In a vacuum, we get the equation $G_{\mu\nu}[g]=0$ (equivalent to $R_{\mu\nu}[g]=0$) for the background metric and $\delta G_{\mu\nu}=0$ for the gravitational waves out of the field equations. Using a corresponding pertubation tensor (similar to the correspondence between the Ricci and Einstein tensor):
\begin{equation}
\delta g_{\mu\nu}'
=\delta g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}(g^{\kappa\lambda}\delta g_{\kappa\lambda})g_{\mu\nu},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\delta g_{\mu\nu}
=\delta g_{\mu\nu}'-\frac{1}{2}(g^{\kappa\lambda}\delta g_{\kappa\lambda}')g_{\mu\nu},
\end{equation}
the equation describing the scattering of gravitational waves is given by:
\begin{equation}
\square\delta g_{\mu\nu}'
+2R_{\kappa\mu\lambda\nu}\delta{g^{\kappa\lambda}}'=0.
\end{equation}
For the Schwarzschild metric in particular using this equation results in the *Regge-Wheeler equation*.

Comment: I think the first link is broken. Could you please give which reference is that?

Comment: Thanks for the remark, it's fixed now. It's "Gravitational Waves" by Claus Lämmerzahl and Volker Perlick from the University of Bremen.