# Initial-value problem for gravitational waves

Tags: waves, gravity, spacetime, metric-tensor

Gravitational waves have been very much in the news recently and I would like to understand them better. I know vaguely that they cause transverse changes to the geometry of matter as they pass by. For many classical wave systems there are integral solutions to the IVP for small disturbances, showing how the wave is driven by gradients, divergences and curls in the initial fields. Are there similar formulas for gravitational waves?

Comment: You may find this question useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769218/226902 See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715968/226902

Comment: @Quillo, Thank you, that points me in a good direcion